# Azure - Where can I find my gph:ClientId?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

Does anyone know where I can find my Azure Active Directory Graph Client ID in Azure?
I have searched everywhere within Azure itself and still no luck. Or if anyone know the powershell command to get the information?

Hopefully someone could point me in the right direction.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You also could get it on Azure Portal.

You could register a new application using the Azure portal, more information about this please refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-integrating-applications).

Client Id is your app's application id.

[image]

You also need grant Graph permission to your app, you also could check the link I provided.

Answer (score 0):

No worries I managed to find it. Had to create B2C tenant through the use of powershell using this link:

https://github.com/blumu/azure-content/blob/master/articles/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-devquickstarts-graph-dotnet.md#register-a-service-application-in-your-tenant

From there it will generate your Client ID. Ensure to make a copy and paste it somewhere for future use.

Comment: Cmdlet `New-MsolServicePrincipal` is an office 365 cmdlet.  In Azure AD, you could get client for Graph Api using on Azure Portal or Azure AD cmdlet, you could check my answer.